# Writing a Nested List of Strings to CSV using CSV helper

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I have a nested list of strings that I would like to write to a CSV file using CSV helper. So, it is a list called `Entries` and each element has a list of strings called `Entry`.

My current code is exporting a blank CSV file.

`Entry` example:

```
{"Date", "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"}
```

and the `Entries` list will have a list of those.

I would like to write to a CSV file with each entry being a new line.

Intended outcome:

```
"Date", "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"
"Date", "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"
"Date", "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"
"Date", "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"
```

My current code:

```cs
var rawDataList = await _siteRepository.GetRawSiteData(siteGuid);

var Entries = _siteRepository.GetSiteData(rawDataList);
var writer = new StreamWriter("YodelTesting.csv");
var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

foreach(var record in Entries)
{
    csv.WriteRecord(record);
}
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the current code to get it working

```cs
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("yodelTesting.csv"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    foreach (var record in output)
    {
        foreach (var field in record)
        {
            csv.WriteField(field);

        }
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
    //not sure what this does tbh
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So is this an answer (then accept your own answer) or more like part of the question and you should rather update your question with this code instead of answering?

Comment: @Ralf Its the answer, I can't accept as answer for 2 days

Comment: You can remove `using (var stream ...`, `using (var reader ...` and `stream.Position = 0`.  You never use those.  Also `writer.Flush();` is not needed.  The using statements on `writer` and `csv` will take care of flushing the `writer`.